# How to label pareto chart as deciles with just showing 10 20 and so on

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2

I have a pareto chart with millions of records. For Y axis I have used the Pareto.Chart() function and showed the quartiles. For x axis I have millions of records and have showed the x points at deciles using scale_x_continuous() but I want to show 10 20 30...100 instead of the numbers. Here is the image of how it is and how I want it[image]

How i want is like this:[image]

I have used ggplot2 and qcc here. I have used pareto.chart() function just to get cummulative sum and then used it in Y. Here is the code part:

```
revenue<-custfinal$Revenue
names(revenue)<-custfinal$customerid
cummulative<-abspareto(revenue, ylab = "Revenue", xlab="Customer", xaxt="n")
cummulative<-data.frame(cummulative)

paretorevenue<-ggplot(data=cummulative, 
               aes(x = seq(1,length(cummulative$Frequency)),y=Cum.Percent.,group=1)) + geom_line(colour="red", size=1) + theme_classic() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, hjust = 1, size=12)) + labs(x="Number of Customer",y="Revenue Share (%)") +ggtitle("Revenue generated distribution for Yogurt 2016") +ylim(0,100.1)+scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(0,length(cummulative$Frequency),length(cummulative$Frequency)/10),-3))    
print(paretorevenue)
```

abspareto() is something which I have edited in pareto.chart() so that it just gives me cummulative part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you provided no example data, I used some data from the ggplot help page. You can change the tick labels using the labels argument within the `scale_x_continuous()` function. There you can include numeric `c(1, 2, 3)` or string vectors `c("a", "b", "c")` as you like. The scale is not changed.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5,
  y1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA),
  y2 = c(NA, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  y3 = c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5)
)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y1))  + geom_line()
p + scale_x_continuous(labels=c(10, 20, 30, 40, "a"))
```

In general, as this is your at least fivth question about this topic, you could try to search for answers or tag your question with `ggplot2` and `geom_line()` rather `pareto chart` as this is a special term not that familiar. I'm convinced that using this search term/headline will answer your questions more rapidly.

Comment: oh i am sorry....you have taken correct sort of exampla... what is the purpose of "a" in the continuous....pardon me I dont know anything about R much just learning i ll try this and get back to you

Comment: oh I didnt know i could use labels along with breaks. Great thanks